# Cannot extract/unwrap value from concatenated Observable

Tags: node.js, rxjs5, angular2-observables

I have this chain which should be concatenating 10 Observables into 1 Observable, where each of the 10 Observables should basically just be unwrapped to an integer:

```
const Rx = require('rxjs');

var i = 0;
const obs = Rx.Observable.interval(10)
  .map(() => i++)
  .map(val => Rx.Observable.create(obs => {
          obs.next(val)
  }))
  .take(10)
  .reduce((prev, curr) => {
      return prev.concat(curr);  // concat all observables
  })
  .last(val => val.flatMap(inner => inner));

// subscribe to Observable
obs.subscribe(v => {
  console.log('\n next (and only) result => \n', v);
});
```

What's happening is that all 10 Observables should be concatenated together, but I cannot extract the values from those 10 Observables (which have become 1 Observable). So my question is, how can I unwrap that final observable and extract the value?

Anyone know what I am talking about?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of reduce + last, you can use concatAll (or concatMap) to concatenate inner sequences and preserve order:

```
Observable
  .interval(0)
  .map(i => Observable.of(i))
  .take(10)
  .concatAll()
  .takeLast(1)
  .subscribe(v => console.log('\n next (and only) result => \n', v);)
```

edit: `takeLast(1)` instead of `finalValue()`

Comment: finalValue() I don't see that in the docs, doesn't seem to be a method on the Observable.prototype.

Comment: If I drop the finalValue call, it seems that concatAll() just grabs the value from the first Observable in the list

Comment: e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41529308/observable-prototype-concatall-does-not-seem-to-yield-expected-result

Answer (score 1):

This question has the exact problem as in [Observable.prototype.concatAll does not seem to yield expected result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41529308/observable-prototype-concatall-does-not-seem-to-yield-expected-result)

```
.map(function(val){  // note: map *not* flatMap
  return Rx.Observable.create(obs => {
      obs.next(val)
  });
})
```

When creating your own observable using `Rx.Observable.create` you need to `.complete()` it yourself. Because you forgot to do so operators like `.reduce()` will not work because they need to wait for completion before being able to run.

Furthermore, your use of the `.last()` operator is incorrect; it takes a predicate on which your stream will be filtered and the last emission matching the predicate will be emitted. It is also a bit redundant because your `.reduce()` will only emit one value. Cleaning it up would lead to:

```
const obs = Rx.Observable.interval(10)
  .map(() => i++)
  .map(val => Rx.Observable.of(val))
  .take(10)
  .reduce((acc, curr) => acc.concat(curr))
  .flatMap(v => v)
  .toArray()
```

But you can shorten this by directly using the `.concatMap()` operator instead of map+take+reduce+flatMap:

```
const obs = Rx.Observable.interval(10)
  .map(() => i++)
  .concatMap(val => Rx.Observable.of(val))
  .take(10)
  .toArray()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the non-prototype method.

```
let range = [...Array(10).keys()];

//array of 10 observables of 10 values each
let ten = range.map(i => Rx.Observable.interval(1000).map(_ => i).take(10));     
let sequence = Rx.Observable.concat(ten) // all of them in sequence
```

Comment: thanks....I tried using this...and ..... sequence.do() is not a function, sequeunce.subscribe() is not a function...what is going on LOL

Comment: I think the library might have some bugs, I cannot explain that

Comment: what I am not liking about this library, it is not returning the same type - Rx.Observable.concat returns different types based off of the input, that is messed up :)

Comment: I highly recommend not using RxJS5.

Comment: haha are you joking or are you serious? do you mean because the library is inconsistent?

Comment: Serious. They've made so many changes of their own, it's not Rx any more. Stick with RxJS4. I don't think there're enough improvements to justify breaking everything.

Comment: yeah, I just started with Rx, so I wouldn't know; I just know RxJS5 is closer to the ES7 Observables spec

Comment: They're considering breaking with the ES7 spec.

Comment: yeah I don't doubt that, we all know that they will have many methods that will not be available in the native spec. They will have the same problems as Bluebird, where the user-land library cannot tap into the same micro-task / task queues as the native library.

Comment: If static `concat` isn't returning an Observable, please file an issue. RxJS 5 is most certainly still Rx, and feel free to provide feedback on any changes (most of which have been made to improve performance) you feel are unwarranted.