# Observable.prototype.concatAll does not seem to yield expected result

Tags: rxjs5, angular2-observables

With this code in mind:

```
const Rx = require('rxjs');

var i = 3;

const obs = Rx.Observable.interval(10)
    .map(() => i++)
    .map(function(val){
        return Rx.Observable.create(obs => {
            obs.next(val)
        });
    })
    .take(10)
    .concatAll();


obs.subscribe(function(v){
    console.log(v);
});
```

I would have expected the logged result to be something like:

```
[3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]
```

That is, 10 values, starting with 3.

However, all we get is just

```
3
```

Does anybody know why that would be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`concatMap` will wait for the first observable to complete before subscribing to the next. You forgot to add the `.complete()` to your inner observable, effectively having your stream only emit the first value `3` and waiting indefinitely for the first stream to complete before concatting the next to it.

Note; for a simple value emission as per your question you can also use `Rx.Observable.of()` instead of `Rx.Observable.create()`

```js
var i = 3;

const obs = Rx.Observable.interval(10)
  .map(() => i++)
  .map(val => Rx.Observable.of(val))
  .take(10)
  .concatAll();

obs.subscribe(v => console.log(v));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/5.0.3/Rx.js"></script>
```

Comment: thank you very much -  I would have thought 100% that the take(10) would eliminate the need for the complete() call which you say is necessary. It makes no sense that you need to call complete(). take(10) should have taken care of that. Sorry but RxJS does not do the right thing in this case IMO.

Comment: As a very simple example Mark:

Comment: const obs = Rx.Observable.interval(10)
    .toArray();

Comment: the above suffers from the problem you describe

Comment: but if you do this:

Comment: const obs = Rx.Observable.interval(10)
    .take(10)
    .toArray();

Comment: the take(10) should be creating a *new* observable which is now complete after a certain time period. *THAT* is why I think my failure to call complete() should not have been failure. however, I will have to check the source code to see if perhaps Rx.Observable.interval "calls complete() on itself" if take(x) is called downstream...........

Comment: `take(10)` will complete your stream after 10 emissions, correct. But the signature of `concatMap` states that it will only concat the next inner stream when the previous completes. Since your inner streams do not complete the `concatMap` will wait forever and `take(10)` does not hit.

Comment: Oh, I see, duh, the inner observables have not completed, that makes sense to me, not sure why I was so dumb to not see that before

Comment: Hi @Olegzandr if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: Sorry Mark I didn't see your comment until just now, justice done tho thanks!